# Change JSON response for registering a user

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

How can I create a hook in FeathersJS that returns the JWT token with the user object in the JSON response after the user is created in the users service?

I've tried in users.hooks.js:

```
 after: {
        all: [
            // Make sure the password field is never sent to the client
            // Always must be the last hook
            protect('password')
        ],
        find: [],
        get: [],
        create: [
            function(hook) {
                const data = {
                    email: hook.data.email,
                    password: hook.data.password,
                    strategy: 'local'
                };

                return hook.app.service('authentication').create(data).then(page => {
                    page.user = hook.result;
                    hook.result = page;
                    return Promise.resolve(hook);
                });
            }
        ],
        update: [],
        patch: [],
        remove: []
    },
```

But the JSON response stays the same. Is it possible to edit the FeathersJS authentication modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar issue when trying to manipulate `context.result` (`hook.result` in your case. You should name it `context` though).

In my understanding, the `hook.result` is a reference to the actual object that gets returned from the service. So, you **can** manipulate that object as you please.

However in your case, you didn't change the actual `result` object, you took another object - `page`, manipulated it, then changed `hook.result` to reference that new object `page`. The actual `result` that  hasn't changed.

```
hook.result = page;
```

The line above is your mistake. What you should do is:

`hook.result.accessToken = page.accessToken`

That way you manipulate the **actual** response object.

I would write your the function like this:

```
 async function (context) {
     const data = {
         email: context.data.email,
         password: context.data.password,
         strategy: 'local'
      };

      const auth = await context.app.service('authentication').create(data);

      context.result.accessToken = auth.accessToken;

      return context;
 }
```

The response JSON would then have the `accessToken` property on it.

Answer (score 0):

To create a user and add a token there are a few things to consider:

1. `hook.data.password` will be the hashed password. The best way to maintain the original login information is to add a hook before `hashPassword` that adds a `params.login` property:

   const setLogin = options => {
     return context => {
       const { data } = context;

   ```
   context.params.login = {
     strategy: 'local',
     email: data.email,
     password: data.password
   };

   return context;
   ```

   };
   };
2. Then you can use `params.login` to create a login. The `authentication` service also requires the `params` from the original request:

   const addAccessToken = () => {
     return async context => {
       const { login } = context.params;

   ```
   const jwt = await context.app.service('authentication')
     .create(login, context.params);

   context.result.accessToken = jwt.accessToken;

   return context;
   ```

   };
   };

Then your `users.hooks.js` file looks similar to this:

```
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    get: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    create: [ setLogin(), hashPassword(), gravatar() ],
    update: [ hashPassword(), authenticate('jwt') ],
    patch: [ hashPassword(), authenticate('jwt') ],
    remove: [ authenticate('jwt') ]
  },

  after: {
    all: [ 
      // Make sure the password field is never sent to the client
      // Always must be the last hook
      protect('password')
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [ addAccessToken() ],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```